# How to get bash script take input from python script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am new to programming in python and wanted to try something out.

I have a bash script, which takes in parameters like User name, Full name etc. This is the bash script I have

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "username: "
read username

echo -n "First name: "
read first

echo -n "Last name: "
read last

echo "$username", "$first", "$last"
```

I am trying to call the bash script via python. Except I want to enter the parameters in python and it needs to be parsed to the bash script. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Python code to call the bash script

```
import os

import sys

os.system("pwd")

os.system("./newuser1.list" )
```

Comment: Include the relevant portions of your scripts here in the body of your question.  What exactly is the problem?  Passing arguments to a Python script?  Passing arguments to a bash script?  Calling bash from Python?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off just using Python's `input()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specific to your python version, but here is something that works with 2.7.

As I understand, you want to take input in the python script and pass it to the bash script. You can use `raw_input("Prompt")` in python 2, and just `input("Prompt")` for python 3. When passing the params to the shell script, simply append them to the string passed to the shell.

As such:

```
import os

user_name = raw_input("Enter username: ")
first_name = raw_input("Enter firstname: ")
last_name = raw_input("Enter lastname: ")

os.system("./test.sh {0} {1} {2}".format(user_name, first_name, last_name))
```

For the shell script, grab the params with the $1, $2... environment style variables. Put them in variables like below, or just use them directly.

The shell script (For the example i named it `test.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

userName=$1
firstName=$2
lastName=$3

echo "$userName, $firstName, $lastName"
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you Andreas this is what i was looking for.